# Seam mail in JBoss6 and Seam3 environment

Tags: java, jboss, seam, jboss6.x, seam3

I'm using Jboss6 with CDI and some Seam3 modules: `seam-solder:3.0.0.Final`, `seam-servlet:3.0.0.Final` and `seam-faces:3.0.1.Final`.
Now I want to add the seam-mail module, but unfortunately it looks not like a release in the next weeks [Seam Website](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/MailModule):

- Current version: N/A
- Maven artifact: TBD
- Distribution: TBD
- Documentation: TBD
- Releases: TBD

Nevertheless I like the idea of templating e-mails in a JSF-style and also use JSF components:

```
<m:message>
  <m:from name="Peter" address="peter@example.com" />
  <m:to name="#{person.firstname} #{person.lastname}">#{person.address}</m:to>
  <m:subject>Try out Seam!</m:subject>
  <m:body>
    <p><h:outputText value="Dear #{person.firstname}" />,</p>
    <p>You can try out Seam by visiting 
    <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.</p>
    <p>Regards,</p>
    <p>Pete</p>
  </m:body>
</m:message>
```

I'm wondering if it's safe to use `org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-mail:2.2.2.Final` in this environment or if i would head to jar hell with this apporach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would surely head to jar hell.

seam-mail from Seam 2.2 is bound to Seam2 core and dependency injection style, while version 3 is built on CDI.

According to some messages in the developer mailing list, sometime in the future there should be a Seam3 compatibility layer for Seam2, but at this time I would not rely on this possibility.